# Difference in these methods of Operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class X
{
    int i;

    public:
    X(int a=0) : i(a) {}

    friend X operator+ (const X& left,const X&right);  

};
X operator+ (const X& left,const X&right)  // Method 1
{
    return X(left.i + right.i);
}

X operator+ (const X& left,const X&right) // Method 2
{
    X temp(left.i + right.i);
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    X a(2),b(3),c;

    c=a+b;

    c.print();
    return 0;
}
```

In this Code, Operator + is overloaded via 2 different method.

My Question is What is the difference between these methods and which should be considered more practical to use ?

Comment: In C++11, `return {left.i + right.i}` is method #3 that ... also does the same thing (after trivial optimizations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't see a case where any compiler would generate different code between those two versions. The second one is slightly more verbose, but the compiler is allowed to optimize away the notional extra copy in that case and I'm not aware of any compiler that wouldn't do that elision.

That said, this is a micro-optimization: Write the code that's clearest, which then brings me to my final point. Don't write either of these operators, but write the idiomatic version in conjunction with `+=`:

```
X& operator+=(const X&right) { i += right.i; return *this; }
X operator+(X left, const X& right) { return left += right; }
```

Comment: +1. @MichaelSmith: I think you should pick this answer, it gives you the right suggestion on how to design your operators.

Comment: If you're planning to make your code `constexpr`, write out `operator +` and then write `operator +=` in terms of that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between those two methods, and you should use the one that best communicates its intent for you.

Paragraph 12.8/31 on *copy elision* specifies:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object
>   have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move
>   operation as simply two different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of that object
>   occurs at the later of the times when the two objects would have been destroyed without the optimization.
>   This elision of copy/move operations, called **copy elision**, is permitted in the following circumstances (which
>   may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> — in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, **when the expression is the name of a
>   non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified
>   type as the function return type**, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing
>   the automatic object directly into the function’s return value
>
> — [...]

As you can see, both the creation of a temporary and an *id-expression* naming a local object with automatic storage duration qualify for copy elision.

Moreover, the compiler will treat the local `temp` like an *rvalue* (read: like a temporary, in this case) for the purposes of returning it from a function. Paragraph 12.8/32 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source
>   object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, **overload resolution to
>   select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue**. [...]

Because of this, I would strongly suggest **removing** the `const` qualification from the return type:

```
    const X operator + (const X& left, const X&right)
//  ^^^^^
//  Don't use this!
```

In C++11, this will inhibit move semantics, because you cannot move from a `const` object, even if it is an rvalue - in short, the move constructor of `X`, provided one exists, will not be picked, and the copy constructor will be called.

Comment: isn't first one using concept of "RVO" ? correct me if i am wrong ?

Comment: Most likely, he meant to make the method const, not the return object.

Comment: @Shashank_Jain: From the point of view of copy elision, those two situations are identical (see 12.8/31). Also, Named Return Value Optimization is a very common extension of RVO

Comment: which answer should i choose . Andy's or Shashank's. both answer are referring to same logic ? yet andy says there is no difference ?

Comment: @MichaelSmith: Those two forms will be treated exactly the same, and copy elision is performed in both cases. Let me add the quote from the Standard

Comment: @MichaelSmith - How about you wait an hour or two to give the community a bit more of a chance to weigh in?

Comment: @AndyProwl - so there is indeed a difference between those method in terms of how compiler sees them ?

Comment: @MichaelSmith: There is a difference in formal terms (in the second case you're returning an rvalue, in the first case you're returning an lvalue), but you won't notice. Compilers will end up optimizing both the same way, so in practice no, there is no difference.

Comment: @AndyProwl - Thanks for this clarifying this crucial doubt !

Comment: @MichaelSmith: You're welcome :) But please consider following Mark B's advice on how to design your operators. I did not want to "steal" that part of the answer so I didn't update mine, but it is indeed the right way to define them.

Comment: @AndyProwl - since i am reading from Book called "introduction to c++ by Bruce Eckel." he said that "const operator+ " , using const as prefix helps in way that user defined object cannot be used as lvalue. and yes this is correct. can you please elaborate your tip on removing const from it ?

Comment: @MichaelSmith: In C++03, where move semantics did not exist, that made sense. However, in C++11 this idiom should be avoided because (as I wrote in the answer) it makes it impossible to *move* from the returned value, since it is `const`.

Comment: ok now i got that tip ! since i use C++03 . so that const plays role for me !

Comment: @MichaelSmith: OK, but don't get used to it ;) My advice is to be aware of what it does and why it is there in C++03 (in case you will have to work with old code), but write new code in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Difference is that Method 1 uses a concept called **"RETURN VALUE OPTIMIZATION".**

Method 1:

When compiler sees that you have no use for the object it is creating other than to return it. The compiler takes advantage of this  and " it build object directly at location of where this value is supposed to be returned to ". here, only one ordinary constructor call is necessary (no copy constructor is required) and there is no destructor call because you never actually created local object. this is more efficient.

---

Method 2:

First temporary object named temp is created. then copy constructor copies the temp to location of the oustide return value.
and then the destructor is called for temp at the end of scope.

**Ultimately Method 1 is more efficient but this is compiler dependent feature.**

Comment: Every non-retarded, modern compiler will emit exactly same code for both versions. Also, you're forgetting about move semantics.

Comment: but in method 2,temporary object is created there including its constructor call.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see why an optimizer would treat those two routines any differently from each other. They are both returning an object created on the spot that is not used for any purpose but returning a value.

Comment: @Shashank_Jain, what? The constructor call is the exact same call in both cases...

Comment: @Griwes - In case of RVO, compiler can skip copy constructor calls. i just read from Wiki page. ! it is true ! .

Comment: @MichaelSmith, well, he did not say he is talking about copy ctor there and totally misused the term "temporary". As for can/can't - I do know, but the exact same optimization will be performed in both cases (assuming we are talking about modern, non-retarded compiler).

Comment: He said that no copy constructor call is required in first case!. yeah method 1 is compiler feature.. and in modern days both are considered same.

Answer (score 0):

The second implementation will cause NRV optimization. Stan Lippman said NRV optimization needed an explicit copy constructor, but here the class X is simple enough so I don't think NRV needs explicit copy constructor.